# Pointer targets in initilization differ in signedness

Tags: c

This is my code i am getting warning pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness. can someone help me out

```
 const uint8_t *activity_output[4] = {"B_STILL", "B_WALk", "B_RUN", "B_UNKNOWN"};
```

Comment: Why do you want to use an array of `uint8_t *` to store `char*`s?

Answer (score 0):

A [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) (ex. `"a string"`) has a `char[N]` type. On you machine `char` is `signed char`. That means that `"B_STILL"` is really a `(signed char[]){"B_STILL"}`, an array of `signed char` bytes.

The `uint8_t` is (usually) a typedef to `unsigned char` and is unsigned type.

Thus when you initialize an `uint8_t *` pointer from a `"B_STILL"` string literal, you convert `char*` pointer (arrays in C automagically decay to pointers to type, ie. `char[N]` decays to `char*` pointer) into a `uint8_t *` pointer. Thus the compiler warn  your - you convert an `signed char*` pointer into `unsigned char*` pointer, they only differ in signedness.

Possible fixes:

1. Move to char. As `activity_output` is an array of strings (ie. `char[]`), one would expect it to have a `char*[]` type, ie. array of pointers to strings. Your intention would be clear then. If you use it later with `printf("%s". ...)`, that's the way to go.

   ```
   const char *activity_output[4] = {
       "B_STILL",
       "B_WALk", 
       "B_RUN", 
       "B_UNKNOWN"
   };
   ```
2. Cast the pointers explicit.

   ```
   const uint8_t *activity_output[4] = {
       (uint8_t*)"B_STILL",
       (uint8_t*)"B_WALk", 
       (uint8_t*)"B_RUN", 
       (uint8_t*)"B_UNKNOWN"
   };
   ```
3. Use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

   ```
   const uint8_t *activity_output[4] = {
       (uint8_t[]){"B_STILL"},
       (uint8_t[]){"B_WALk"}, 
       (uint8_t[]){"B_RUN"}, 
       (uint8_t[]){"B_UNKNOWN"}
   };
   ```

Comment: Thank you Kamil for suggestion.  I will try with unsigned char*